# How to hide delete icon in kartik Detail view yii2?

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I am using Kartik/Detail View. I only want to show the edit button in the panel and hide delete icon in the panel.My code is :

```
<?= DetailView::widget([

    'model' => $model,
    'mode' => 'view',
    'bordered' => true,
    'striped' => true,
    'panel' => [
        'heading' => $this->title,
        'type' => DetailView::TYPE_INFO,
    ],
   'container' => ['id'=>'kv-demo'],
    'responsive' => true,
    'hover' => true,
    'hAlign'=>true,
    'vAlign'=>true,

    'fadeDelay'=>true,
        'attributes' => [

            'business_name',                
            'address2',
            'city',
            'state',
            'zip',
            'telephone',
            'fax',
            'email:email',
        ],
    ]) ?>
```

How can I hide delete icon ?

Answer (score 3):

http://demos.krajee.com/detail-view#option-buttons1

Use **'buttons1' => '{update}',** to hide delete.

```
<?= DetailView::widget([

'model' => $model,
'mode' => 'view',
'bordered' => true,
'striped' => true,
'panel' => [
    'heading' => $this->title,
    'type' => DetailView::TYPE_INFO,
],
'buttons1' => '{update}',
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this from _columns.php file of view folder with following option 
Here you can add template with action that you need to show in the detail view (in this example view action is used and Assign with fa-gear icon is displayed in view)

```
[
    'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
    'dropdown' => false,
    'vAlign'=>'middle',
    'template' => '{view}',
    'urlCreator' => function($action, $model, $key, $index) {
        return Url::to([$action,'id'=>$key]);
    },
    'buttons'=>[
        'view' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
            return Html::a('<span class="fa fa-gears"> Asign</span>', ['view', 'id'=>$model->id],['title'=>'Asign','role'=>'modal-remote','data-toggle'=>'tooltip']);
        },
    ]
],
```